# Conversion from UTF8 to ASCII

Tags: c#, encoding, utf-8, ascii

I have a text read from a XML file stored in UTF8 encoding. C# reads it perfectly, I checked with the debugger, but when I try to convert it to ASCII to save it in another file I get a ? char in places where there was a conflicting character. For instance, this text:

```
string s = "La introducción masiva de las nuevas tecnologías de la información";
```

Will be saved as

```
"La introducci?n masiva de las nuevas tecnolog?as de la informaci?n"
```

I cannot just replace them for their latin (a, e, i, o, u) vowels because some words in spanish would miss the sense. I've already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138449/how-to-convert-a-unicode-character-to-its-ascii-equivalent) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497782/how-to-convert-a-string-from-utf8-to-ascii-single-byte-in-c) questions with no sucess. So Im hoping someone can help me. The selected answer in the second one didnt even compiled...!

In case someone wants to take a look, my code is this one:

```
private void WriteInput( string input )
{
   byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
   byte[] asciiArray = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.ASCII, byteArray);
   string finalString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(asciiArray);

   string inputFile = _idFile + ".in";
   var batchWriter = new StreamWriter(inputFile, false, Encoding.ASCII);
   batchWriter.Write(finalString);
   batchWriter.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Those characters have no mapping in ASCII. Review an ASCII table, like [Wikipedia's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), to verify this. You might be interested in the Windows 1252 encoding, or "extended ASCII", as it's sometimes called, which has code points for many accented characters, Spanish included.

```
var input = "La introducción masiva de las nuevas tecnologías de la información";
var utf8bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
var win1252Bytes = Encoding.Convert(
                Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1252"), utf8bytes);
File.WriteAllBytes(@"foo.txt", win1252Bytes);
```

Comment: @David: works perfectly for me, using the test case above. Make sure you don't have an ASCII encoding (Encoding.ASCII) stuck in your code somewhere.

Comment: Sorry about that! tested again and works like a charm... Now I know why you have 18.3K rep!!! ;)

Comment: I would add much more +1's if I could! :)

Answer (score 9):

Can't be done. ASCII does not have those letters, so the best you can do is to URL-encode or unicode-escape-encode them.

Comment: How come? If ASCII doesnt have those letters how can I change the encoding from UTF8 to ASCII using Notepad++ and works like a charm?

Comment: Because Notepad++ isn't really using ASCII. It's using something like CP1250, which *does* have those letters.

Comment: Notepad++ converts to Win-1252 codepage (Latin), which has the accented in the higher half of the table (char codes 128+). However, that's not ASCII, that's an expansion of ASCII. ASCII only defines chars in the 0-127 range. Meanwhile, opening that file on a machine set with a different codepage, will show different characters in place of the accented one. In Win-1251 for example, you would see some Cyrillic letters instead.