# write UTF-8 characters as Ascii into a file

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, ascii, hebrew

I'm trying to convert Hebrew characters from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-8-1 in order to save them into a file.
I have read about ten posts here , in this site,
no matter what I do, I always get question marks (???????) instead of hebrew letters.
I tried `iconv()`, `mb_convert_encoding()`, `utf8_decode()`, all of them convert from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-8-1 but I keep getting '?????????' in the file.

```
mb_convert_encoding($fullRecord, 'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8');
iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", $fullRecord);
iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $fullRecord);
```

Even this post didn't help because the solution there is in javascript:
[Conversion from UTF8 to ASCII](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352209/conversion-from-utf8-to-ascii)
I wish it could be in php...

I know that there are no hebrew characters in ASCII, but i have an example file that shows it can be done. when I open the file in notepad , it shows hebrew ok and the file is ANSI , so I guess it can be done somehow...

anyone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
iconv("UTF-8", "windows-1255", $fullRecord);
```

Comment: Yes!!!!! its working!!! i guess i should read more about windows-1255. the file opens in notepad with correct hebrew characters and the file is still ANSI. thank you :)