# Replace characters in a string to fit browser, C#, From UTF8 encoding

Tags: string, browser, utf-8

I need to replace the characters å, ä, ö to browser friendly chars. For example ä should become %E4.

I tried weirdString = Uri.EscapeUriString(weirdString);
But it doesnt convert the åäö to the right sign. Help please?

Edit: Tried this:

```
ASCIIEncoding ascii = new ASCIIEncoding(); 
byte[] asciicharacters = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("vägen");
byte[] asciiArray = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.ASCII, asciicharacters);
string finalString = ascii.GetString(asciiArray);
string fixedAddrString = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(finalString);
```

Comment: "å" is a perfectly browser friendly character. What are you trying to do/what's the problem you're encountering?

Comment: For instance, I need "dadelvägen" to become "dadelv%E4gen". Otherwise I get the wrong HTML-page.

Comment: Do you mean in the *URL* or in the *HTML*?

Comment: What are you getting instead of the expected values?

Comment: With HtmlEncode I get "v&#228;gen".

Answer (score 1):

If you need the characters to display on the *page* and not part of a URL, you should use [`Server.HtmlEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.htmlencode.aspx).

```
var encodedString = Server.HtmlEncode(myString);
```

> HTML encoding makes sure that text is displayed correctly in the browser and not interpreted by the browser as HTML. For example, if a text string contains a less than sign (<) or greater than sign (>), the browser would interpret these characters as the opening or closing bracket of an HTML tag. When the characters are HTML encoded, they are converted to the strings < and >, which causes the browser to display the less than sign and greater than sign correctly.

---

Update:

Since you are using UTF-8, these characters are escaped to UTF-8, not ASCII.

You need to convert the string from UTF-8 to ASCII, using the `Encoding` classes before you try to escape them. That is, if you do want the ASCII values to come up.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497782/how-to-convert-a-string-from-utf8-to-ascii-single-byte-in-c).

Comment: It was meant to be used in the URL.

Comment: @mdc - You will need to convert the string to an ASCII string before encoding.

Comment: Cant get it right with converting it to ASCII, whats wrong here: (See OP, pasted the code there). The final string only becomes "v?gen" Not "v%E4gen".

Comment: @mdc - Have you checked the result of the encoding?

Comment: Yes I get a questionmark for the "ä" for some reason, probably doing it wrong. I would really appreciate if you could experiment with that letter ("ä") for a couple a minute to see if you can make it "%E4". Its driving me mad now =).

Comment: @mdc - Try using `UnicodeEncoding` instead of `UTF8` (only available in .NET 4.0).

Comment: How are you getting the original string? Are you certain it is UTF-8?

Comment: Yes its UTF-8, but I had to give up and move on. It took too much time. I just did an ugly hack with Strings Replace method to replace the characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try HttpUtility.HtmlDecode.
If this doesent working too you can do a simple string.Replace for this chars.

Comment: I think he meant HtmlEncode, I tried that but the resulting string for "vägen" becomes "v&#228;gen", it should be "v%E4gen".

Comment: Its what I used with HtmlEncode. How can I get the correct string?