# How to convert a string to UTF8?

Tags: c#, .net, character-encoding

I have a string that contains some unicode, how do I convert it to UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: i think this helps to you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497782/how-to-convert-a-string-from-utf8-to-ascii-single-byte-in-c

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This snippet makes an array of bytes with your string encoded in UTF-8:

```
UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
string unicodeString = "Quick brown fox";
byte[] encodedBytes = utf8.GetBytes(unicodeString);
```

Comment: Why not just use `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes` rather than `new`ing up another encoder?

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer This snippet is from one of [Microsoft's examples for the UTF8Encoding class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.utf8encoding.aspx). I am not 100% certain why they choose to do it this way, but I would assume it's for thread safety (they mention that instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe, but this is only my guess).

Comment: @CAS I have no idea, please ask a separate question.

Answer (score 4):

Try this function, this should fix it out-of-box. You may need to fix naming conventions though.

```
private string UnicodeToUTF8(string strFrom)
{
    byte[] bytSrc;
    byte[] bytDestination;
    string strTo = String.Empty;

    bytSrc = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(strFrom);
    bytDestination = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Unicode, Encoding.ASCII, bytSrc);
    strTo = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytDestination);

    return strTo;
}
```

Comment: Use this to make your strings 
1. XML compatible before saving to database, 
2. (or) CSV compatible before exporting to CSV

Comment: Your function name says  UTF8, yet your code says:  ACII ?? Confusing at least.

Answer (score 3):

This should be with the minimum code:

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(myString);
myString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

Answer (score 2):

try to this code

```
 string unicodeString = "Quick brown fox";
 var bytes = new List<byte>(unicodeString);
        foreach (var c in unicodeString)
            bytes.Add((byte)c);
        var retValue = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes.ToArray());
```