# How to convert UTF-8 characters to ASCII for use in a URL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dotnetnuke

I want to automatically convert UTF-8 characters like `â Ù á Č Ģ` to `a U a C G` so that they would be acceptable in a URL.

So far I have this:

```
Encoding sourceEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(28591); // ISO-8859-1

byte[] asciiBytes = Encoding.Convert(sourceEncoding, Encoding.ASCII, sourceEncoding.GetBytes(<source text>));

String asciiString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(asciiBytes);
```

Two problems with this approach:

1. This works fine for some characters (Č and Ģ), but for others (â, Ù, á) it returns a question mark in place of the character.
2. The whole site is in UTF-8, not ISO-8859-1, but when I set sourceEncoding to Encoding.UTF8 all of the characters are converted to question marks, so it doesn't work at all.

Got any ideas how I could make this work?

Comment: Is there a reason you are not simply [url-encoding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/575440/url-encoding-using-c-sharp) these characters?

Comment: This was answered already [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497782/how-to-convert-a-string-from-utf8-to-ascii-single-byte-in-c) Make sure that your charcan be displayed at ASCII.
Hope it answers your question

Comment: If you really want to remove diacritics, look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3769995/41071).

Comment: @Jon: I want to keep URL encoded characters in URLs to a minimum. I want all the characters that have ASCII equivalents to be displayed as their ASCII equivalents (Ģ->G, â->a, ...).

Comment: @svick: This method doesn't always give ASCII characters.

Comment: @David Rasuli: I would need an answer for ASP.Net 2.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249087/how-do-i-remove-diacritics-accents-from-a-string-in-net

Answer (score 6):

You can remove diacritic marks (often called accent marks, you know: tilde, cédille, umlaut and friends) best using [normalization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8eaxk1x2.aspx).

The following method should replace 99% of all diacritic marks. The last percent will however still be displayed as ?. If you don't want to see the ? characters, replace them after using this method with an empty string.

```
public static string RemoveDiacritics(string value)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        return value;

    string normalized = value.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (char c in normalized)
    {
        if (System.Globalization.CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c) != System.Globalization.UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark)
            sb.Append(c);
    }

    Encoding nonunicode = Encoding.GetEncoding(850);
    Encoding unicode = Encoding.Unicode;

    byte[] nonunicodeBytes = Encoding.Convert(unicode, nonunicode, unicode.GetBytes(sb.ToString()));
    char[] nonunicodeChars = new char[nonunicode.GetCharCount(nonunicodeBytes, 0, nonunicodeBytes.Length)];
    nonunicode.GetChars(nonunicodeBytes, 0, nonunicodeBytes.Length, nonunicodeChars, 0);

    return new string(nonunicodeChars);
}
```

Hope that helps!